# My test class does not enter the execute method

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a class scheduler that calls my bacth class, it executes the start method but doesn't enter the execute, below are my classes

---

My class Schedulable

```java
global class BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosSchedulable implements Schedulable{
    
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        
        Id recordExpurgoId = Schema.SObjectType.EK6_ParametroDeSolicitacao__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('BA_Expurgo').getRecordTypeId();

        List<EK6_ParametroDeSolicitacao__c> parametros = [SELECT EK6_ValorTxt__c
                                                          FROM EK6_ParametroDeSolicitacao__c 
                                                          WHERE RecordTypeId =: recordExpurgoId
                                                          AND Expurgo_Ativo__c  = true];
    
        if (!parametros.isEmpty()){
            
            String valor;
            for(EK6_ParametroDeSolicitacao__c c: parametros){
                valor = c.EK6_ValorTxt__c;
                Break;
            }
            
            Date myDate = Date.today();
            Date newDate = myDate.addMonths(-(Integer.valueOf(valor)));

            BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosBatch expurgoEmailsAtivo = new BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosBatch(newDate);
            Database.executeBatch(expurgoEmailsAtivo, 100);
            
        }
    }
}
```

My class batch

```java
public class BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    
    public Set<Id> recordTypeIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    public Date dataExpurgo;
    
    public BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosBatch(){
        
    }
    
    public BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosBatch(Date dataExpurgo){
        
        this.dataExpurgo = dataExpurgo;
       
        
        Id operacaoCambioId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('EK6_Operacao_Cambio').getRecordTypeId();
        Id atendimentoTelefonicoId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('EK6_Atendimento_Telefonico_Cambio').getRecordTypeId();
        Id operacaoCambioRDId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('EK6_Operacao_Cambio_Read_Only').getRecordTypeId();
        Id operacaoGocId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('EK6_Operacao_GOC').getRecordTypeId();
        Id operacaoComexId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('EK6_Operacao_Comexpress').getRecordTypeId();
        Id operacaoGocRDId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Opera_o_GOC_Read_Only').getRecordTypeId();
        
        this.recordTypeIdSet.add(operacaoCambioId);
        this.recordTypeIdSet.add(atendimentoTelefonicoId);
        this.recordTypeIdSet.add(operacaoCambioRDId);
        this.recordTypeIdSet.add(operacaoGocId);
        this.recordTypeIdSet.add(operacaoComexId);
        this.recordTypeIdSet.add(operacaoGocRDId);
    }
    
    public Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {        
        
        return [SELECT caseNumber,EK6_ParaEmailCliente__c,EK6_CopyItauAddressMail__c,EK6_BackupEmailParaTxt__c,
                (SELECT ParentId,Subject,Headers,Incoming,CreatedDate,CreatedBy.FirstName,CreatedBy.LastName,BA_CopiaOriginal__c,MessageDate,LastModifiedDate,
                 CcAddress,BccAddress,ToAddress,FromAddress,HtmlBody,TextBody,
                 FromName,BA_ParaOriginal__c,Status,LastModifiedBy.FirstName,LastModifiedBy.LastName
                 FROM EmailMessages) 
                 FROM case 
                 WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId  FROM EmailMessage WHERE CreatedDate >=: this.dataExpurgo AND hasAttachment = true)
                 AND RecordTypeId IN: this.recordTypeIdSet LIMIT 1];
        
        
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> caseList) {
        
        try {
            List<Id> parent = new List<Id>();
            
            for(Case b: caseList){
                
                for(EmailMessage d: b.EmailMessages){
                    
                    parent.add(d.ParentId);    
                }     
            }
            
            List<ContentDocumentLink> documentLinkEmailsIdList = [SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id,LinkedEntityId,ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM EmailMessage where ParentId IN: parent) ORDER BY LinkedEntityId];
            
            List<Id> idAnexo = new List<Id>();
            
            for(ContentDocumentLink iddoc : documentLinkEmailsIdList){
                idAnexo.add(iddoc.ContentDocumentId);
            }
            
            List<ContentVersion> listaAnexos = [SELECT ContentDocumentId,versiondata,Title,FileExtension FROM Contentversion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN: idAnexo AND IsLatest = true ORDER BY ContentDocumentId];
            
            Map<String, List<sObject>> mapListAnexo = new Map<String, List<sObject>>();
            
            for(ContentDocumentLink linkEmail: documentLinkEmailsIdList){
                
                List<ContentVersion> listFiles = new List<ContentVersion>();
                
                for(ContentVersion anexo: listaAnexos){
                    
                    if(anexo.ContentDocumentId == linkEmail.ContentDocumentId){
                        
                        listFiles.add(anexo);  
                    }  
                }
                
                mapListAnexo.put(linkEmail.LinkedEntityId,listFiles);
            }
            
            String payload = this.criarJson(caseList, mapListAnexo);   
            System.debug('payload= ' + payload);
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug(e);
        }
        
    }   
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        
    }
    
    public String criarJson(List<Case> listaCasos, Map<String ,List<sObject>> anexos){
        
        Map<String, Object> mapEmailUnico = new Map<String, Object>();
        Map<String,Object > mapPayload = new Map<String,Object>();
        
        List<Object> listaEmails = new List<Object>();
        
        if(!listaCasos.isEmpty()){
            
            for(Case caso: listaCasos){ 
                
                String numeroCaso = caso.CaseNumber;
                String emailPara = caso.EK6_ParaEmailCliente__c;
                String emailCopia = caso.EK6_CopyItauAddressMail__c;
                String remetente = caso.EK6_BackupEmailParaTxt__c;
                Id IdCaso = caso.Id;      
                
                List<EmailMessage> listaEmailMessage = new List<EmailMessage>{caso.EmailMessages};
                    
                    for(EmailMessage email: listaEmailMessage){
                        
                        List<Object> listaAnexos = new List<Object>();
                        
                        if(!anexos.isEmpty()){
                            
                            List<ContentVersion> listaAnexosEmail = anexos.get(email.Id);

                            for(ContentVersion registro: listaAnexosEmail){
                                Map<String,Object> mapAnexo = new Map<String,Object> {
                                    
                                    'mime_type' => this.mimeType(registro.FileExtension),
                                    'nome_arquivo' => registro.Title + '.' + registro.FileExtension,
                                    'id_lote_documento' => numeroCaso,
                                    'upload_documento ' => registro.versiondata
                                  };
                                        
                                        listaAnexos.add(mapAnexo);
                            }
                        }

                        Map<String, Object> mapEmail = new Map<String, Object> {
                            
                                'documentos'                                =>  listaAnexos,
                                'nome_usuario_ultima_alteracao'             => email.LastModifiedBy.FirstName + ' ' + email.LastModifiedBy.LastName ,
                                'texto_email_remetente'                     => remetente , 
                                'texto_email_destinatario_para_tratado'     => email.ToAddress , 
                                'texto_email_destinatario_para_original'    => emailPara , 
                                'texto_email_destinatario_copia_oculto'     => email.BccAddress ,
                                'texto_email_destinatario_copia_tratado'    => emailCopia ,
                                'texto_email_destinatario_copia_original'   => email.BA_CopiaOriginal__c  , 
                                'data_hora_criacao'                         => email.CreatedDate ,
                                'data_hora_ultima_alteracao'                => email.LastModifiedDate ,
                                'data_hora_mensagem'                        => email.MessageDate , 
                                'nome_usuario_criacao'                      => email.CreatedBy.FirstName + ' '+ email.CreatedBy.LastName ,
                                'texto_corpo_email'                         => email.TextBody ,
                                'texto_corpo_html'                          => email.HtmlBody ,
                                'indicador_chegada'                         => email.Incoming ,
                                'codigo_solicitacao'                        => numeroCaso ,
                                'texo_cabecalho_email'                      => email.Headers,
                                'texto_assunto_email'                       => email.Subject,
                                'identificador_status_email'                => email.Status
                                
                    };
                    listaEmails.add(mapEmail);
                        
                }                
            }
            
            mapPayload.put('Emails',listaEmails);
        }
        
        String pretty = JSON.serializePretty(mapPayload);
       
        return pretty;
    }
    
    public String mimeType(String mime){
        
        String mimeType;
        
        switch on mime {
            when 'aac' {
                mimeType = 'audio/aac';
            }
            when 'abw' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-abiword';
            }
            when 'arc' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-freearc';
            }
            when 'avi' {
                mimeType = 'video/x-msvideo';
            }
            when 'azw' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.amazon.ebook';
            }
            when 'bin' {
                mimeType = 'application/octet-stream';
            }
            when 'bmp' {
                mimeType = 'image/bmp';
            }
            when 'bz' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-bzip';
            }
            when 'bz2' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-bzip2';
            }
            when 'csh' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-csh';
            }
            when 'css' {
                mimeType = 'text/css';
            }
            when 'csv' {
                mimeType = 'text/csv';
            }
            when 'doc' {
                mimeType = 'application/msword';
            }
            when 'docx' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
            }
            when 'eot' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject';
            }
            when 'epub' {
                mimeType = 'application/epub+zip';
            }
            when 'gz' {
                mimeType = 'application/gzip';
            }
            when 'gif' {
                mimeType = 'image/gif';
            }
            when 'htm','html' {
                mimeType = 'text/html';
            }
            when 'ico' {
                mimeType = 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon';
            }
            when 'ics' {
                mimeType = 'text/calendar';
            }
            when 'jar' {
                mimeType = 'application/java-archive';
            }
            when 'jpeg','jpg' {
                mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
            }
            when 'js' {
                mimeType = 'text/javascript';
            }
            when 'json' {
                mimeType = 'application/json';
            }
            when 'jsonld' {
                mimeType = 'application/ld+json';
            }
            when 'mid' {
                mimeType = 'audio/midi';
            }
            when 'midi' {
                mimeType = 'audio/x-midi';
            }
            when 'mjs' {
                mimeType = 'text/javascript';
            }
            when 'mp3' {
                mimeType = 'audio/mpeg';
            }
            when 'mpeg' {
                mimeType = 'video/mpeg';
            }
            when 'mpkg' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.apple.installer+xml';
            }
            when 'odp' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation';
            }
            when 'ods' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet';
            }
            when 'odt' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text';
            }
            when 'oga' {
                mimeType = 'audio/ogg';
            }
            when 'ogv' {
                mimeType = 'video/ogg';
            }
            when 'ogx' {
                mimeType = 'application/ogg';
            }
            when 'opus' {
                mimeType = 'audio/opus';
            }
            when 'otf' {
                mimeType = 'font/otf';
            }
            when 'png' {
                mimeType = 'image/png';
            }
            when 'pdf' {
                mimeType = 'application/pdf';
            }
            when 'php' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-httpd-php';
            }
             when 'ppt' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
            }
             when 'pptx' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
            }
             when 'rar' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.rar';
            }
             when 'rtf' {
                mimeType = 'application/rtf';
            }
             when 'sh' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-sh';
            }
             when 'svg' {
                mimeType = 'image/svg+xml';
            }
             when 'swf' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
            }
             when 'tar' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-tar';
            }
             when 'tif','tiff' {
                mimeType = 'image/tiff';
            }
             when 'ts' {
                mimeType = 'video/mp2t';
            }
             when 'ttf' {
                mimeType = 'font/ttf';
            }
             when 'txt' {
                mimeType = 'text/plain';
            }
             when 'vsd' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.visio';
            }
             when 'wav' {
                mimeType = 'audio/wav';
            }
             when 'weba' {
                mimeType = 'audio/webm';
            }
             when 'webm' {
                mimeType = 'video/webm';
            }
             when 'webp' {
                mimeType = 'image/webp';
            }
             when 'woff' {
                mimeType = 'font/woff';
            }
             when 'woff2' {
                mimeType = 'font/woff2';
            }
             when 'xhtml' {
                mimeType = 'application/xhtml+xml';
            }
             when 'xls' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
            }
             when 'xlsx' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
            }
             when 'xml' {
                mimeType = 'application/xml';               
            }
             when 'xul' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml';
            }
             when 'xlsm' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12';
            }
            when 'xlsb' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12';
            }
             when 'zip' {
                mimeType = 'application/zip';
            }
             when '3gp' {
                mimeType = 'video/3gpp';
            }
             when '3g2' {
                mimeType = 'audio/video';
            }
             when '7z' {
                mimeType = 'application/x-7z-compressed';
            }
            when 'aces' {
                mimeType = 'image/aces';
            }
            when 'jp2' {
                mimeType = 'image/jp2';
            }
            when 'jph' {
                mimeType = 'image/jph';
            }
            when 'vnd.microsoft.icon' {
                mimeType = 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon';
            }
            when 'tiff-fx' {
                mimeType = 'image/tiff-fx';
            }
            when 'avci' {
                mimeType = 'image/avci';
            }
            when 'avcs' {
                mimeType = 'image/avcs';
            }
            when 'avif' {
                mimeType = 'image/avif';
            }
            when 'jpm' {
                mimeType = 'image/jpm';
            }
            when 'cgm' {
                mimeType = 'image/cgm';
            }
            when 'dicom-rle' {
                mimeType = 'image/dicom-rle';
            }
            when 'emf' {
                mimeType = 'image/emf';
            }
            when 'example' {
                mimeType = 'image/example';
            }
            when 'heif' {
                mimeType = 'image/heif';
            }
            when 'svg+xml' {
                mimeType = 'image/svg+xml';
            }
            when 'docm' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12';
            }
            when 'dotx' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template';
            }
            when 'dotm' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12';
            }
            when 'potm' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12';
            }
            when 'potx' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template';
            }
            when 'ppam' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12';
            }
            when 'pps' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow';
            }
            when 'ppsx' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow';
            }
            when 'ppsm' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12';
            }
            when 'pptm' {
                mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12';
            }
   
        }
        return mimeType;
        
    }
    
}
```

My class test

```java
@isTest
public class BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosBatchTest {
    
    @TestSetup
    public static void dadosSetup(){
        
        Id recordExpurgoId = '012q00000006cAsAAI';
        
        EK6_ParametroDeSolicitacao__c param = new EK6_ParametroDeSolicitacao__c(
            Expurgo_Ativo__c = true,
            RecordTypeId = recordExpurgoId,
            EK6_ValorTxt__c = '1'
        );
        insert param;
        
        List<Case> casos = new List<Case>();
        for(Integer i=0; i<2; i++) {
        casos.add(new Case());
        }
        insert casos;
        
        List<EmailMessage> emails = new List<EmailMessage>();
        
        for(Case caso : casos){
            
            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(
                ParentId = caso.Id
                );
            emails.add(email);    
        }
        insert emails;
        
        /*ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink(
            ContentDocumentId = '069q0000001XdMkAAK',
            LinkedEntityId = email.Id
        );
        insert link;
        
        ContentVersion versao = new ContentVersion(
            VersionData = Blob.valueOf('JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhwdC1CUikgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDEwIDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnV'),
            PathOnClient = 'image001.jpeg',
            ContentDocumentId = link.ContentDocumentId
        );
        insert versao;*/
        
    }
    
    @isTest
    public static void testScheduler(){
        
        BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosSchedulable baReqSch = new BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosSchedulable();
        
        String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?';

        System.Test.startTest();
        
            System.schedule('Test', sch, baReqSch);
        
        System.Test.stopTest();
    }

    public static testMethod void test() {
        

        //BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosSchedulable baReqSch = new BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosSchedulable();

        System.Test.startTest();
        
         BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosBatch test = new BA_ExpurgoEmailsAnexosBatch();
         database.executeBatch(test, 200);
                
        System.Test.stopTest();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Cannot recommend strongly enough against a pattern of `try { /*entire method*/ } catch { /*no persistent handling*/ }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the reason why your batch `execute()` method isn't being called is because your `start()` method returns no results.

The query in your `start()` method includes `WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId  FROM EmailMessage WHERE CreatedDate >=: this.dataExpurgo AND hasAttachment = true)`.

I see that your test is inserting `EmailMessage` records, but you're not adding any records that would cause the `hasAttachment` flag to be set to true. Hence, your `start()` method would return no records for the execute() method to operate on.

I'm not sure if that `hasAttachment` field on EmailMessage is set when you add an `Attachment` with ParentId = your email message record's Id, or if it requires a `ContentDocumentLink` with LinkedEntityId = your email message record's Id.

It'd be easier to test if `hasAttachment` is based on having a related `Attachment` record, because that's just a single additional record to create.

If it does require a `ContentDocumentLink`, then you'd need (from my memory of working with Content Documents about 7 years ago):

- A content library with author permissions for a specific profile
- A user with the target profile
- Creating a `ContentDocument` record (in your test class) with firstPublishLocationId = your target library Id
- Finally, creating a `ContentDocumentLink` to relate your EmailMessage and the test ContentDocument

Comment: even removing this condition (AND hasAttachment = true ), still without executing the method

Comment: @Rabelo Your tests are also not setting `dataExpurgo`. Doing comparisons against null values can have unexpected results (though I think they should be deterministic)